# Python: remove row when a row element consists of string within row name

Tags: python, dataframe, delete-row

I have dataframe:

```
        Col1   Col2    
Rowab1   3     5
Rowbc2   4     6
Rowxy3   7     2
```

I want to search the dataframe and only keep the row where the row name contains "bc" like this while deleting rest of the rows:

```
        Col1   Col2
Rowab1   3     5
Rowxy3   7     2
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(['bc'])]
```

However, this does not search for "bc" within a string but it searches for an entire independent string "bc". Is there any "like" operator that I can possibly incorporate such as

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(['%bc%'])]  ?
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may be looking for [`pandas.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative with [`pd.Series.str.find`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.find.html):

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
        Col1  Col2
Rowab1     3     5
Rowbc2     4     6
Rowxy3     7     2

In [42]: df[df.index.str.find('bc') > -1]
Out[42]: 
        Col1  Col2
Rowbc2     4     6
```

Answer (score 2):

You said in your post you wanted every row *not containing* "bc" to be deleted. Here are a variety of solutions:

Using a simple string-membership test:

```
>>> df.ix[[i for i in df.index if 'bc' in i]]
        Col1  Col2
Rowbc2     4     6
```

Using regular expressions and the `re` module:

```
>>> df.ix[[i for i in df.index if re.match('.+bc.+', i)]]
        Col1  Col2
Rowbc2     4     6
```

You could also use [`pandas.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html), as I alluded to in the comments:

```
>>> df[pd.Series(data=df.index, index=df.index).str.match('.+bc.+')]
        Col1  Col2
Rowbc2     4     6
```

You can't directly use `pandas.Series.str.match` on a [`pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) object, so I just converted it to a `pandas.Series` object with effectively garbage as the values. The you can use the `str` accessor that comes with `Series` objects.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks blacksite!